# how to change json key:value

Tags: json, replace, set

```
//my json data    
var jsndata = "{ "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" },
            { "id": "5009", "type": "Juice" }"
```

How would i change `"type": "Chocolate"` => `"type": "only water"`
or.. `"id": "5005"` => `"id": "1234"`

My list is very long.. I need get or set any value ?

Note: My list is dynamic and always sorting order by id or type..

Will `jsndata.id['5003']='1234'` change it?

`var getval = jsndata.id['5005'].type` get val..(value Sugar) ?

Comment: Your JSON string is not well formatted. You need `[...]` around the objects.

Comment: your JSON string is not correct, cosider using different types of quotes.

Comment: It looks to me like you have syntax errors in your code. You should fix it so that the quotation marks are in the right places. In the real code you're working with, are you using a string which contains the entire dataset, or are you using an object literal? It's not clear from your example.

Comment: `jsndata.id['5003']='1234'` is wrong syntax.

Comment: Btw. it might be even better to restructure your data to a format that makes it more efficient to apply changes. Always looping over all your data is ver inefficient!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<script>
var json = [{ "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" },
            { "id": "5009", "type": "Juice" }];
/**
 * The function searches over the array by certain field value,
 * and replaces occurences with the parameter provided.
 *
 * @param string field Name of the object field to compare
 * @param string oldvalue Value to compare against
 * @param string newvalue Value to replace mathes with
 */
function replaceByValue( field, oldvalue, newvalue ) {
    for( var k = 0; k < json.length; ++k ) {
        if( oldvalue == json[k][field] ) {
            json[k][field] = newvalue ;
        }
    }
    return json;
}

/**
 * Let's test
 */
console.log(json);

replaceByValue('id','5001','5010')
console.log(json);

replaceByValue('type','Chocolate','only water')
console.log(json);
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Spot On! Thanks.

Comment: can it also change the datatype of value like if I want to change {"abc":123} to {"abc":[]} can it be done by your code?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Pinch](https://github.com/Baggz/Pinch), a (multi) data replacement tool for JavaScript objects/JSON. Here is a brief example how *pinch.js* could be used in your case:

```
var data = [
  {
    id: 5001,
    type: 'None'
  },
  {
    id: 5002,
    type: 'Glazed'
  },
  {
    id: 5005,
    type: 'Sugar'
  },
  {
    id: 5003,
    type: 'Chocolate'
  },
  {
    id: 5004,
    type: 'Maple'
  },
  {
    id: 5009,
    type: 'Juice'
  }
];

pinch(data, '/id/', function(path, key, value) {
  return (value === 5001) ? 5010 : value;
});
```

Comment: Awesome method name for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

try this. simplified.

```
var json = [{ "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" },
                { "id": "5009", "type": "Juice" }];           

        var JsonObject= JSON.parse(json);
            $.each(JsonObject, function(key,value) {
                if( JsonObject[key].id=='5005' ){
                    JsonObject[key].id='1234';
                }             

                if( JsonObject[key].type=='Chocolate' ){
                    JsonObject[key].type='Only water';
                }

            });
```

Comment: i get this `VM159:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1(…)` for `var JsonObject= JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: not in my side i have already tested it . please share a test  link if you have time ( = .

Answer (score 1):

modified the function from above to be able to change all values of a key,and increment it by 1.
And you can pass in the jsonObj

```
function replaceByValue( jsonObj, field, oldvalue, newvalue ) {
    for( var k = 0; k < jsonObj.length; ++k ) {
             jsonObj[k][field] = (newvalue *1)+k;

    }
    return jsonObj;
}
```

//example

```
var json = [{ "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" },
                { "id": "5009", "type": "Juice" }]; 


json; 

replaceByValue( json, "id", "na", 123 );

json;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple key-value pairs,you may use like this:

```js
var json = [{
  "AppSettings": {
    "OBiAccessDomain": "ABCD",
    "WebserviceUrlTokens": {
      "$OBiWebService$": "http://",
    }
  }
}];

function replaceSingleField( field, oldvalue, newvalue ) {
         if( oldvalue == json[0]['AppSettings'][field] ) {
             json[0]['AppSettings'][field] = newvalue ;
         }
    return json;
}

function replaceTwoField( field1, field2, oldvalue, newvalue ) {
        if( oldvalue == json[0]['AppSettings'][field1][field2] ) {
             json[0]['AppSettings'][field1][field2] = newvalue ;
         }
    return json;
}



replaceSingleField('OBiAccessDomain','ABCD','XYZ');
console.log(json[0]);

replaceTwoField('WebserviceUrlTokens','$OBiWebService$','http://','https://');
console.log(json[0]);
```