# json for sending same set of values

Tags: json, jsonp

I need to send the same set of vaules in json format .

i.e I have two set of key and values , key name is same and values are diffrent , I need something like an array of strings .

key[10] = {names}
values[10] ={values}

I tried like below format

{
  ...
  "retweeted_status" : {
    ...
    "id_str" : "114345368862461952",
    ...
  },
  ...
  "id_str" : "114369052268437504",
  ...
}
but it requires lot of space.

can somebody tell how to represent in this (arrays) in  json format to send  and parse properly using standrad json .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for, Found here: [how to change json key:value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553235/how-to-change-json-keyvalue)

```
<script>
var json = [{ "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" },
        { "id": "5009", "type": "Juice" }];
/**
 * The function searches over the array by certain field value,
 * and replaces occurences with the parameter provided.
 *
 * @param string field Name of the object field to compare
 * @param string oldvalue Value to compare against
 * @param string newvalue Value to replace mathes with
  */
 function replaceByValue( field, oldvalue, newvalue ) {
    for( var k = 0; k < json.length; ++k ) {
    if( oldvalue == json[k][field] ) {
        json[k][field] = newvalue ;
    }
}
return json;
}

 /**
 * Let's test
  */
console.log(json);

replaceByValue('id','5001','5010')
console.log(json);

replaceByValue('type','Chocolate','only water')
console.log(json);
</script>
```