# Play2 Json replace key

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I receive JSON object in request, is it possible to replace some key by another in Play2?

Change JSON:

```
{ "name" : "My name" }
```

for example to:

```
{ "nameAndSurname" : "My name" }
```

I have much more complex JSON. Can I use JSON transformers?

I'm using Scala here is simple example:

```
val json = Json.obj("name" -> "My name")
json.transform() <======== ???
```

Comment: You should write more details, i.e. it's definitelly other approach in Java and Scala... which language do you use?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553235/how-to-change-json-keyvalue

Comment: it's too old question, I hope something has changed by 3 years

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fairly simple. Here's an example that should help:

```
case class User(nameAndSurname: String, age: Int)

implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "age").read[Int]
)(User.apply _)

// controller
...
json.validate[User] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[User] => {
    val user: User = s.get
    // do something with user
  }
  case e: JsError => {
    // error handling flow
  }
```

}

Comment: But I need to resend modified json, with this solution I have a redundant parsing, the best would be if I could transform in some way this json

Comment: spent 30 minutes googling today, thanks for providing the answer I was looking for!!!