# replace part of string in value of json

Tags: javascript, replace

i want to replace 11111 to <, and 22222 to > in json

My code:

```js
var json_A = {
  "question1": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/RQpTQBw.png`22222",
    "enum": ["Adrian", "Attams", "Adrienne"],
    "requested": false
  },
  "question2": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/SHB02L8.png`22222",
    "enum": ["She does.", "No.", "Yes"],
    "requested": false
  }
}


function replaceValueOfJson(json, field, oldvalue, newvalue) {
  for (var k = 0; k < json.length; ++k) {
    if (oldvalue == json[k][field]) {
      json[k][field] = newvalue;
    }
  }
  return json;
}

var string_format = replaceValueOfJson(json_A,'title','11111','aaaaa')
//alert(string_format)
console.log(string_format)
```

My desired output:

```json
{
  "question1": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "<img src=`https://i.imgur.com/RQpTQBw.png`>",
    "enum": ["Adrian", "Attams", "Adrienne"],
    "requested": false
  },
  "question2": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "<img src=`https://i.imgur.com/SHB02L8.png`>",
    "enum": ["She does.", "No.", "Yes"],
    "requested": false
  }
}
```

Related topic: [how to change json key:value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553235/how-to-change-json-keyvalue)

How can i change above function to get correct output?

My link: https://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/y5gs9jwp/28/

Comment: Your code doesn't have any JSON in it.  The value named `json_A` is a native JavaScript object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
JSON.parse((JSON.stringify(json_A)).replaceAll('11111', '<').replaceAll('22222', '>'));
```

Comment: This will cause a SyntaxError with  `{ aNumber: 11111, anotherNumber: 22222 }` as input.

Comment: Maybe he chose these patterns precisely because he knows it won't be repeated anywhere else, it's risky, but it should work for him

Answer (score 2):

Just indent json and you'll see the problem:

```
var json_A =
    { 
        "question1": {
            "type":"string",
            "title":"11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/RQpTQBw.png`22222",
            "enum":["Adrian","Attams","Adrienne"],
            "requested":false },
        "question2":{
            "type":"string",
            "title":"11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/SHB02L8.png`22222",
            "enum":["She does.","No.","Yes"],
            "requested":false }
    }
```

Still don't see it ? here:

```js
var json_A ={"question1":{"type":"string","title":"11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/RQpTQBw.png`22222","enum":["Adrian","Attams","Adrienne"],"requested":false},"question2":{"type":"string","title":"11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/SHB02L8.png`22222","enum":["She does.","No.","Yes"],"requested":false}}

Object.keys(json_A).forEach(question=>{
    json_A[question].title = json_A[question].title.replace('11111','<');
    json_A[question].title = json_A[question].title.replace('22222','>');
});

console.log(json_A)
```

Linear iterating an hierarchical structure won't do any good. You have to consider json levels.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive solution (will modify the original object):

```js
function replaceValueInJSON(object, keyToChange, callback) {
    if (keyToChange in object) {
        // If object has the given key, run callback on the corresponding value
        object[keyToChange] = callback(object[keyToChange]);
    }
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        // Recursively check in non-array object children which has not been processed.
        if (
            key !== keyToChange &&
            value instanceof Object && !(value instanceof Array)
        ) {
            replaceValueInJSON(value, keyToChange, callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Try it:

```js
function replaceValueInJSON(object, keyToChange, callback) {
  if (keyToChange in object) {
    object[keyToChange] = callback(object[keyToChange]);
  }
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if (
      key !== keyToChange &&
      value instanceof Object && !(value instanceof Array)
    ) {
      replaceValueInJSON(value, keyToChange, callback);
    }
  }
}

const objectToChange = {
  question1: {
    type: 'string',
    title: '11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/RQpTQBw.png`22222',
    enum: ['Adrian', 'Attams', 'Adrienne'],
    requested: false
  },
  question2: {
    type: 'string',
    title: '11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/SHB02L8.png`22222',
    enum: ['She does.', 'No.', 'Yes'],
    requested: false
  }
};

replaceValueInJSON(objectToChange, 'title', oldValue => {
  return oldValue.replaceAll('11111', '<').replaceAll('22222', '>');
});

console.log(objectToChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects don't have a `length` property. (Unless you manually add one)

Instead, you can iterate over [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and execute [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the field of your choice like this:

```js
var json_A = {
  "question1": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/RQpTQBw.png`22222",
    "enum": ["Adrian", "Attams", "Adrienne"],
    "requested": false
  },
  "question2": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "11111img src=`https://i.imgur.com/SHB02L8.png`22222",
    "enum": ["She does.", "No.", "Yes"],
    "requested": false
  }
}


function replaceValueOfJson(json, field, oldvalue, newvalue) {
  for (let obj of Object.values(json)) {
    obj[field] = obj[field].replace(oldvalue, newvalue);
  }
  return json; // This isn't really necessary as this will modify the object passed to it in-place
}

replaceValueOfJson(json_A,'title','11111','<');
replaceValueOfJson(json_A,'title','22222','>');

console.log(json_A)
```

`Object.values()` returns an array of the values in the object passed through it.